# Looping in table to get TDs' results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to loop through `table` tds to get specific cells data to insert them on a database, the problem is that when I push the results to an array they appear with each other not separate tds results, do I miss something?

**Results**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 22
    [3] => All quantity finally confirmed
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 9
    [7] => Not all quantity finally confirmed
)
```

**Function**

```
function UpdateResults()
{
   var table = $('#SearchResults');
   var OrderID;
   var CatID;
   var ProID;
   var Status;
   var data = [];

   table.find('tbody tr').each(function() 
   {
        OrderID = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html(); 
        CatID = $(this).find("td").eq(3).html(); 
        ProID = $(this).find("td").eq(4).html(); 
        Status = $(this).find("td:eq(6) select").val();
        data.push(OrderID,CatID,ProID,Status);
   });  

jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url : 'UpdateResults.php',
    data : {'Data':jsonString}

  }).done(function(response) {
     alert ("Done");
  });
}
```

Comment: Why don't your create an array, and push it into `data` instead of pushing all the results at once?

Comment: Please add your html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push the data as pairs using a js object that will be converted to a associative array in php:

```
table.find('tbody tr').each(function() 
   {
        OrderID = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html(); 
        CatID = $(this).find("td").eq(3).html(); 
        ProID = $(this).find("td").eq(4).html(); 
        Status = $(this).find("td:eq(6) select").val();
        data.push({OrderID:OrderID,CatID:CatID,ProID:ProID,Status:Status});
   });
```

php:

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $data) {
echo $data['OrderID'];
}
```